# How to convert list of comma separated Ids into their name?

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table that contains:

```
id   task_ids
1    10,15
2    NULL
3    17
```

I have the table that has the names of this tasks:

```
id  task_name
10    a
15    b
17    c
```

I want to generate the following output

```
id task_ids task_names
1   10,15    a,b
2    null    null
3    17      c
```

I know this structure isn't ideal but this is legacy table which I will not change now.

Is there easy way to get the output ?
I'm using Presto but I think this can be solved with native sql

Comment: Fix your data model so you are not storing lists of numbers in a string.  That is the root of your problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i'm aware. But this is legacy table. we query it 1-2 times a year. It's on cold storage. no need to put effort on refactoring it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1, '10,15'), (2, NULL)) x(id, task_ids)
),
task AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('10', 'a'), ('15', 'b')) x(id, task_name)
)
SELECT
    d.id, d.task_ids
    -- array_agg will obviously capture NULL task_name comping from LEFT JOIN, so we need to filter out such results
    IF(array_agg(t.task_name) IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ARRAY[NULL], NULL, array_agg(t.task_name)) task_names
FROM data d
-- split task_ids by `,`, convert into numbers, UNNEST into separate rows
LEFT JOIN UNNEST (split(d.task_ids, ',')) AS e(task_id) ON true
-- LEFT JOIN with task to pull the task name
LEFT JOIN task t ON e.task_id = t.id
-- aggregate back
GROUP BY d.id, d.task_ids;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a horrible data model, but you can do what you want with a bit of effort.  Arrays are better than strings, so I'll just use that:

```
select t.id, t.task_id, array_agg(tt.task_name) as task_names
from t left join lateral
     unnest(split(t.task_ids, ',')) u(task_id)
     on 1=1 left join
     tasks tt
     on tt.task_id = u.task_id
group by t.id, t.task_id;
```

I don't have Presto on hand to test this.  But this or some minor variant should do what you want.

EDIT:

This version might work:

```
select t.id, t.task_id,
       (select array_agg(tt.task_name)
        from unnest(split(t.task_ids, ',')) u(task_id) join
             tasks tt
             on tt.task_id = u.task_id
       ) as task_names
from t ;
```

Comment: Note: Presto doesn't support LEFT JOIN UNNEST with a condition just yet. There is an open PR for this: https://github.com/prestosql/presto/pull/1679.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen . . . Can you do this with a correlated subquery?

Comment: You mean `JOIN LATERAL`? That's already supported (of course, for the queries which the engine can decorrelate).

Comment: I tried the version in the edit... get Given correlated subquery is not supported
cc @PiotrFindeisen

Comment: @HaloKu please join `#troubleshooting` channel on Presto Community Slack (https://prestosql.io/slack.html) for "more interactive" troubleshooting.